# how can i force handling .../ih/... as a php script

Tags: apache, url, seo, url-rewriting, short

I have numerous index.php scripts using SEO-friendly arg format like

example.com/path/to/index.php/opt/arg

and would like to rewrite or force a handler to have

example.com/path/to/ih/opt/arg

and thus shorten the index.php part.  [Well, I'd like to get rid of it entirely, but don't want to go back to

example.com/path/to/?opt&arg

format.]  This should be generally supported in any dir on the site rather than requiring .htaccess, alias, or http.conf modification.  For my next trick I'll expand 'ih' for PHP to also cover 'ip' for Perl, 'ir' for Ruby, 'iy' for Python, and perhaps others.  [My original thought was just 'i' but then I realized that there are other languages for which I'll want this as well.]

I've tried playing with MultiViews but clearly don't know what I'm doing :-)  I've looked extensively at mod_rewrite but just can't see how to implement something like this.  I took a quick look at forcing a handler but 1) am not sure that's really what I mean (and so I beg forgiveness in advance for perhaps using the wrong term) and 2) have the added fun challenge of running 1.3 where I host vs 2.2 at home :-)

Suggestions?

TIA & HAND

### :-D

David T-G
http://justpickone.org/davidtg/email/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you looked into using mod_rewrite, I'm going to assume you don't mind making a one-time change to `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`, but just don't want to have to do it for every index.php on your site. (Correct me if I'm wrong!)

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\/)?ih(\/.*)?$ $1index.php$2 [L,QSA]
```

You may not need the two `RewriteCond`s. They just check that the original URL did not exist as an actual file on the system, before rewriting that URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I tried this but now get a server error and "Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable confguration error." in my log. Thoughts?

Comment: What else do you have in your .htaccess and httpd.conf? I tried it on my shared hosting account and it seemed to work, so maybe you have another rewrite rule somewhere that is interacting to cause a loop?

Comment: Hi again! Nothing in a .htaccess file, and you can surf over to http://justpickone.org/davidtg/private/rewrites/ to see my httpd.conf and included testme.conf file.  I've tried it with and without the second <Directory> block with no change.  Thanks, so much, again!

Comment: I tried out your config files on a fresh Apache and PHP install on Windows, using a "hello world" `test/index.php`, and wasn't able to see the error. I think your best bet might be to try the same, and if it works for you with all default settings, then gradually add things (server config, parts of your PHP script) until it breaks. That might narrow it down... Myself, I don't know enough to diagnose it without doing similar experiments. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much, antinome.  I'll try this as soon as I can and will be back!

Comment: Hiya! First, thanks again and I owe antinome some feedback, since I was actually able to get this to work, sort of.  I use aliases on my local install, and I had to reset my DocRoot to "c:/" in order to really get things to work.  That is a separate question, though :-)